# In SignalR, how long do messages stay in backplane

Tags: garbage-collection, signalr

Just recently started using SignalR with a SQL server backplane for use in a web farm. How long do the messages stay in the `SignalR.Message_0` table before they are erased? It looks as though it garbage collects messages older than 12hrs, but not on a regular basis.

Is there a supported way to set that Message Lifetime amount, or to manually call the garbage collect?
Also is the default lifetime the same across all four backplanes? (SQL Server, Redis, Azure, and local)

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer/send.sql#L34

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignalR is open source, take a look:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer/send.sql#L34